# PHP atualizando registros com sql = UPDATE

Tags: php, sql-update, instanciar-objeto

Estou com problema na passagem desse objeto para a função que atualiza os dados do usuário. O id do usuário está na variável $usuario['ID']. Na função a comparação atende ao pedido identificando o usuário corretamente, mas a atualização apaga os dados pré-existentes no banco de dados, e não deixa nada do que foi passado no objeto $objetoUsuario, como se as variáveis estivessem vazias. Já testei,usando o comando echo, e verifiquei que os valores digitados nos campos são passados para as funções getNome, getSenha, getEmail e getEndereco quando o formulário é submetido, mas não está dando certo nessa passagem para a função Editar.

Fragmento do arquivo editar_usuario.php

```
session_start();
$controllerUsuario = new UsuarioController();
$usuario = $controllerUsuario->getUsuario($_SESSION["usuario_id"]);
if (isset($_POST['editar'])) { 

$objUsuario = new Usuario();
$objUsuario->setNome($_POST['nome']);
$objUsuario->setSenha($_POST['senha']);
$objUsuario->setEmail($_POST['email']);
$objUsuario->setEndereco($_POST['endereco']);


$controllerUsuario = new Usuario();

$resposta = $controllerUsuario->Editar($usuario['ID'],$objUsuario);
```

Fragmento do arquivo Usuario.php com as classes e funções de negociação com o banco de dados.

```
    public function Editar($id) {

    $objConexao = new Conexao();
    $conexao = $objConexao->getConexao();

    $sql = "UPDATE  Usuarios set Nome = '".$this->nome."', Email = '".$this->email."',Senha = '".$this->senha."', Endereco = '".$this->endereco."' WHERE id = ".$id;


    if (mysqli_query($conexao, $sql)) {return "Sucesso";}
    else {return "Erro na tentativa de editar";}
    mysqli_close($conexao);
}
```

Comment: Você está passando **2** parâmetros na função `$controllerUsuario->Editar($usuario['ID'],$objUsuario);` porém a função só recebe **1** parâmetro `function Editar($id)` 

Comment: E, no caso, são objetos diferentes. Se vai atualizar com base nos dados do `$objUsuario`, o "correto" é fazer `$objUsuario->Editar($usuario['ID'])`. Isso deve resolver o seu problema ao usar os dados setados

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário, Heinrich! Testei dessa forma e funcionou. Notei que o problema era que eu estava passando o objeto $objUsuario pelo outro objeto $controllerUsuario, e lá na função ele se perdia. E era essa a instrução que o curso passava.

Comment: Não escreva *[Resolvido]* nos titulos das perguntas. Para indica uma pergunta como solucionada basta aceitar uma resposta. Veja [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta).

Answer (score -1):

Depois de muitas tentativas eu consegui resolver o problema mudando a forma de passagem do objeto. Ao invés de passar as variáveis $_POST para as funções setters, passei-as diretamente para a função de alteração do banco de dados. Eu estava seguindo uma instrução dada no curso do SENAC que foi muito mal elaborado.
Lá, mandava passar assim:

```
$objUsuario = new Usuario($_POST['nome'], $_POST['senha'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['endereco']);
$controllerUsuario = new Usuario();

$resposta = $controllerUsuario->editaUsuario($usuario['ID'],$objUsuario);
```

e receber assim:

```
   public function Editar($id) {

$objConexao = new Conexao();
$conexao = $objConexao->getConexao();

$sql = "UPDATE  Usuarios set Nome = '".$this->nome."', Email = '".$this->email."',Senha = '".$this->senha."', Endereco = '".$this->endereco."' WHERE id = ".$id;
```

O que não tem sentido, pois a passagem acima não mandava os dados para os setters, então, não tinha como recebê-los pelo $this->

Tentei enviá-los pelos setters, mas não sabia que com a sessão inicializada a passagem era esvaziada nos $this->

Então, fiz assim:

Passagem:

```
    $objUsuario = new Usuario($_POST['nome'], $_POST['senha'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['endereco']);
$controllerUsuario = new Usuario();

$id=$usuario['ID']; // esse foi o jeito que eu fiz para poder receber o id na função sem as [].

$resposta = $controllerUsuario->Editar($id,$objUsuario);
```

O recebimento da maneira mais trivial:

```
    public function Editar($id,$objUsuario) {

    $objConexao = new Conexao();
    $conexao = $objConexao->getConexao();

    $sql = "UPDATE  Usuarios set Nome = '".$_POST['nome']."', Email = '".$_POST['email']."',Senha = '".$_POST['senha']."', Endereco = '".$_POST['endereco']."' WHERE id = ".$id;
```

E assim, funcionou!

Comment: Amigos, depois de testar a sugestão do Heinrich, vi que o problema estava na passagem de objeto dentro de outro objeto, e era por isso que a informação se perdia lá na função.

Comment: Seja objetivo. Sem cumprimentos e agradecimentos nas publicações, esses causam ruído que aqui buscamos evitar. Concentre-se no conteúdo técnico. Se fizer muita questão de agradecer use o campo de comentários.

Answer (score -2):

O $this->nome e outros campos para pegar os dados e enviar na BD estão a apontar na variável local, e elas estão vazias. Use o get de cada campo para pegar os valores.

Exemplo: $this->getNome()…

Abraços!

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, Invisível7!
Fiz a alteração para 
  $sql = "UPDATE  Usuarios set Nome = '".$this->getNome()."', Email = '".$this->getEmail()."',Senha = '".$this->getSenha()."', Endereco = '".$this->getSenha()."' WHERE id = ".$id;

Mas continua a apagar as informações no banco de dados.

Comment: Pelo que entendi, o problema está na  inicialização de sessão, que faz o objeto esvaziar-se na passagem para a função. Mas ainda não compreendi como passá-lo de maneira que os dados não se percam. Editei a postagem para incluir mais conteúdo do código.

Comment: Mas no poste você diz que os valores aparecem quando você faz um echo nos gets! Então não é a instância do objecto, se assim fosse… o echo também retornaria vazio. Ou o seu problema está quando você seta os valores que vêm do formulário. Tenta setar usando o ponto: $objecto.setNome(…);